# Angular Firestore updating specific document field on button click

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'M trying to set the 'orderCompleted' field in a document to true when the button is clicked. However when I tried to do this nothing happens. I have wrote a function called 'updateOrderComplete()' to update the field in firebase and then I'm calling it on a button click but it does not update.

**Component:**

```
export class OrdersComponent{
  orders: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(public firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.orders = firestore.collection('Order', ref=>
    ref.where('orderCompleted', '==', false).orderBy('collectionTime', 'asc')).valueChanges();
  }

  // markComplete = data => this.markComplete(data);

  updateOrderComplete(_id: string){
   let doc = this.firestore.collection('Order', ref => ref.where('objectId', '==', _id));
   doc.snapshotChanges().subscribe((res: any) => {
     let id = res[0].payload.doc.id;
     this.firestore.collection('Order').doc(id).update({orderCompleted: true})
   })
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="card-footer">
                          <button style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-light" (click)="updateOrderComplete">
                              Complete
                          </button>
                      </div>
```

Comment: update is a promise, can you add then and catch and see if you get any error or it goes to success?

Comment: Where will I have to add the then and catch? sorry im new to angular

Comment: after `update()`

Comment: `this.firestore.collection('Order').doc(id).update({orderCompleted: true}).then(() => console.log('success')).catch(err => console.error(err))`

Comment: getting this error now after changing the click even in html
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res[0].payload')

**New click event**
`   <button style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-light" (click)="updateOrderComplete(order)">
                              Complete
                          </button>`

Comment: it means it didnt get to `update` at all, is `objectId` different than the `id` of document?